# Why no function template matches function template specialization with different return type in that example?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Why does a compilation error occur when trying to set a different return value instead of auto for an explicit template specialization? Why compile error here:

```
template <size_t T>
auto Get() = delete;

template <>
auto Get<0>(){
    return 5;
}

std::string str = "Hello world!";

template <>
std::string const & Get<1>() {
    return str;
}

int main() {
    func_employee();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `auto` return type is not a template parameter here

Comment: @TheDreamsWind So why then is this possible? The returned types are different after compile
https://wandbox.org/permlink/zZ6ACliOVaGm7mpp

Comment: @HamsterGamer that code doesn't compile.

Comment: my mistake, fixed: https://wandbox.org/permlink/bUxcW3oNSYrJS9mV

Comment: If your question why you can specialise `auto` in either scenario, then I believe it's because the compiler considers `auto` return-type part of the function signature. If you use anything but `auto` it becomes another function declaration

Comment: The rule that causes this to be ill-formed is [dcl.spec.auto.general/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec.auto#general-13) - if you specialize a function template with a placeholder return type (`auto` or `decltype(auto)`), then the same placeholder type **must** be used for the specialization.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `auto Get()` is the functions signature which has nothing to do with the template parameters. If you want to be able to specialise return type explicitly, you have to add a corresponding parameter for it:

```cpp
template <size_t S, typename R>
R Get() = delete;
```

The template specialisations can remain the same in this case but the `auto` return type doesn't make much sense anymore, because I can't see how it can be used to instantiate the template, so you may want to replace it with desired integral type:

```cpp
template <>
int Get<0>(){
    return 5;
}
```

Finally, function templates don't deduce its arguments based on return type, so you will have to specify it explicitly in this case:

```cpp
auto integral = Get<0, int>();
auto string = Get<1, std::string const &>();
```